# Circular matching. PHP / MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I need some help with the following scenario in php. I have a db with users every user has an ID, have_card and want_card. I know how to make a direct match (one user trades with another user). But if there is no direct match but there is a circular swap like:

User #1 has card A wants card B

User #2 has card B wants card C

User #3 has card C wants card A

In this scenario there is no direct match between two users. But if:

User #1 gives his card to User #3

User #3 gives his card to User #2

User #2 gives his card to User #1

Every ones happy.

All the info I have to start with is User #1 how do I find User #2 and User #3?

Thanks to everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a challenging scenario.  I had to build this for a book swapping application a while back and using a white board I was able to more easily visual and solve the problem.

What I did was use the same table inside the query multiple times, just using a different name.

In my scenario, the books that were needed were in a separate table from the books the users had.  Hopefully you'll be able to see the logic in this query:

```
$query = "SELECT 
        A.Owner_ID as Owner_1, C.Owner_ID as Owner_2, E.Owner_ID as Owner_3 
    FROM
        E_User_Books_Have as A, E_User_Books_Have as C, E_User_Books_Have as E,
        E_User_Books_Needed as B, E_User_Books_Needed as D,E_User_Books_Needed as F

    WHERE 
        A.Book_ID=D.Book_ID AND
        C.Book_ID=F.Book_ID AND
        E.Book_ID=B.Book_ID AND 
        A.Owner_ID='$ME' AND B.Owner_ID='$ME' AND A.ID='$ID'AND 
        C.Owner_ID=D.Owner_ID AND  
        E.Owner_ID=F.Owner_ID AND
        C.Owner_ID!='$ME' AND
        E.Owner_ID!='$ME'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, I came across a similar thing to this with the [BoardGameGeek Maths Trade](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/93555).  Basically, everyone specifies that they either want a game or have a game and the algorithm maximises trades including circular dependencies.

This is exactly what you want.

Here is an [explanation of how TradeMaximizer works](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/TradeMaximizer).  It uses [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [skew heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_heap) to find minimal matching solutions (ie a smaller circle is preferable to a larger circle).

Granted this is created in Java but algorithms are universal and you can recreate it as required, particularly once you understand what it's doing and why.

Comment: +1 for using graph theory (as opposed to the other hackish suggestions).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it: 
Create a recursive algorithm like this:

1 take one user, see what he wants

2 find another user who has what user one wants

```
- if user two wants, what user one has, everything is fine an we're done
- if not, continue
```

3 find another user who has what user two wants

```
- if user three wants, what user one has, everything is fine and we're done
- if not, continue ...
```

... and so on, but you should a have limit for recursive levels to prevent endless searching.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

Finding possible first matches (users who have the card user#1 wants)

```
select name from user where has in (select wants from user where name = '1');
```

Iterate through those matches and try finding the missing link:

```
select name from user where name in (select name from user where has in (select wants from user where name = <match>));
```